# Android DragShadowBuilder view refresh

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview

I'm implementing drag'n'drop feature into my application.
I'm moving `TextView` object, and I'm using `DragShadowBuilder` to build shadow for this textview.
The question is, is there any way to change textView text while dragging item? I mean in 
`DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED` or `DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION` case?

Answer (score 0):

Since API 24, now there is [View.updateDragShadow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#updateDragShadow(android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder)) that you can call every time you need a visual change in your shadow.

You can even use the same shadow instance from startDragAndDrop() as argument again and it will call onProvideShadowMetrics and onDrawShadow to reflect any changes.

Answer (score -2):

```
private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

// The drag shadow image, defined as a drawable thing
private static Drawable shadow;

    // Defines the constructor for myDragShadowBuilder
    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {

        // Stores the View parameter passed to myDragShadowBuilder.
        super(v);

        // Creates a draggable image that will fill the Canvas provided by the system.
        shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    // Defines a callback that sends the drag shadow dimensions and touch point back to the
    // system.
    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch)
        // Defines local variables
        private int width, height;

        // Sets the width of the shadow to half the width of the original View
        width = getView().getWidth() / 2;

        // Sets the height of the shadow to half the height of the original View
        height = getView().getHeight() / 2;

        // The drag shadow is a ColorDrawable. This sets its dimensions to be the same as the
        // Canvas that the system will provide. As a result, the drag shadow will fill the
        // Canvas.
        shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

        // Sets the size parameter's width and height values. These get back to the system
        // through the size parameter.
        size.set(width, height);

        // Sets the touch point's position to be in the middle of the drag shadow
        touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    // Defines a callback that draws the drag shadow in a Canvas that the system constructs
    // from the dimensions passed in onProvideShadowMetrics().
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

        // Draws the ColorDrawable in the Canvas passed in from the system.
        shadow.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

[Drag n drop android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)